# Multithreading within a loop c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, directory

I am making a tool using c# that iterates through a large file directory and extracts certain information. The directory is organised by language (LCID), so I want to use multithreading to go through the directory- one thread per language folder.

My code currently scans through a small number of the files and extracts the required data without multithreading, but on a large scale it will take too long.

I set up a thread within my loop that gets the LCID folders, but got the following error: "no overload for 'HBscan' matches delegate System.threading.threadstart". From what I read online, I then put my method within a class so I could have parameters, and now there's no errors but the code is not iterating through the files properly. It is leaving files out of it's scan.

I was wondering if anyone could see where I was going wrong with my code that's making it not perform properly? Thanks.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //change rootDirectory variable to point to directory which you wish to scan through
        string rootDirectory = @"C:\sample";
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(rootDirectory);

        //get the LCIDs from the folders
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory);
        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
        {
            string LCID = filePaths[i].Split('\\').Last();
            Console.WriteLine(LCID);

            HBScanner scanner = new HBScanner(new DirectoryInfo(filePaths[i]));
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(scanner.HBscan));              
            t1.Start();             
        } 

        Console.WriteLine("Scanning through files...");

    }
    public class HBScanner
    {
        private DirectoryInfo DirectoryToScan { get; set; }

        public HBScanner(DirectoryInfo startDir)
        {
            DirectoryToScan = startDir;
        }

        public void HBscan()
        {
            HBscan(DirectoryToScan);
        } 

        public static void HBscan(DirectoryInfo directoryToScan)
        {
            //create an array of files using FileInfo object
            FileInfo[] files;
            //get all files for the current directory
            files = directoryToScan.GetFiles("*.*");
            string asset = "";
            string lcid = "";

            //iterate through the directory and get file details
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                String name = file.Name;
                DateTime lastModified = file.LastWriteTime;
                String path = file.FullName;

                //first check the file name for asset id using regular expression
                Regex regEx = new Regex(@"([A-Z][A-Z][0-9]{8,10})\.");
                asset = regEx.Match(file.Name).Groups[1].Value.ToString();

                //get LCID from the file path using regular expression
                Regex LCIDregEx = new Regex(@"sample\\(\d{4,5})");
                lcid = LCIDregEx.Match(file.FullName).Groups[1].Value.ToString();

                //if it can't find it from filename, it looks into xml
                if (file.Extension == ".xml" && asset == "")
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("File is an .XML");
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("file.FullName is: " + file.FullName);
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.Load(path);
                    //load XML file in 

                    //check for <assetid> element
                    XmlNode assetIDNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("assetid")[0];
                    //check for <Asset> element
                    XmlNode AssetIdNodeWithAttribute = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Asset")[0];

                    //if there is an <assetid> element
                    if (assetIDNode != null)
                    {
                        asset = assetIDNode.InnerText;
                    }
                    else if (AssetIdNodeWithAttribute != null) //if there is an <asset> element, see if it has an AssetID attribute
                    {
                        //get the attribute 
                        asset = AssetIdNodeWithAttribute.Attributes["AssetId"].Value;

                        if (AssetIdNodeWithAttribute.Attributes != null)
                        {
                            var attributeTest = AssetIdNodeWithAttribute.Attributes["AssetId"];
                            if (attributeTest != null)
                            {
                                asset = attributeTest.Value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Item newFile = new Item
                {
                    AssetID = asset,
                    LCID = lcid,
                    LastModifiedDate = lastModified,
                    Path = path,
                    FileName = name
                };

                Console.WriteLine(newFile);

            }

            //get sub-folders for the current directory
            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = directoryToScan.GetDirectories("*.*");
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs)
            {
                HBscan(dir);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try it *on a large scale*. Considering your program is IO intensive, it sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: Do files get left out of the scan when you just create and call the scanner instead of initiating threads?

Comment: I have been told to use multithreading, so I need to implement it.

Comment: No, when HBscan is not a class, just a method, the files are scanned correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I havent checked, but i think this could work.

The code will create one scanner per thread and perform the HBscan method.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //change rootDirectory variable to point to directory which you wish to scan through
            string rootDirectory = @"C:\sample";
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(rootDirectory);

            //get the LCIDs from the folders
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory);
            for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
            {
                string LCID = filePaths[i].Split('\\').Last();
                Console.WriteLine(LCID);

                Thread t1 = new Thread(() => new HBScanner(new DirectoryInfo(filePaths[i])).HBscan());
                t1.Start();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Scanning through files...");

        }
        public class HBScanner
        {
            private DirectoryInfo DirectoryToScan { get; set; }

            public HBScanner(DirectoryInfo startDir)
            {
                DirectoryToScan = startDir;
            }

            public void HBscan()
            {
                HBscan(DirectoryToScan);
            }

            public static void HBscan(DirectoryInfo directoryToScan)
            {
                //create an array of files using FileInfo object
                FileInfo[] files;
                //get all files for the current directory
                files = directoryToScan.GetFiles("*.*");
                string asset = "";
                string lcid = "";

                //iterate through the directory and get file details
                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {
                    String name = file.Name;
                    DateTime lastModified = file.LastWriteTime;
                    String path = file.FullName;

                    //first check the file name for asset id using regular expression
                    Regex regEx = new Regex(@"([A-Z][A-Z][0-9]{8,10})\.");
                    asset = regEx.Match(file.Name).Groups[1].Value.ToString();

                    //get LCID from the file path using regular expression
                    Regex LCIDregEx = new Regex(@"sample\\(\d{4,5})");
                    lcid = LCIDregEx.Match(file.FullName).Groups[1].Value.ToString();

                    //if it can't find it from filename, it looks into xml
                    if (file.Extension == ".xml" && asset == "")
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("File is an .XML");
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("file.FullName is: " + file.FullName);
                        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                        xmlDoc.Load(path);
                        //load XML file in 

                        //check for <assetid> element
                        XmlNode assetIDNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("assetid")[0];
                        //check for <Asset> element
                        XmlNode AssetIdNodeWithAttribute = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Asset")[0];

                        //if there is an <assetid> element
                        if (assetIDNode != null)
                        {
                            asset = assetIDNode.InnerText;
                        }
                        else if (AssetIdNodeWithAttribute != null) //if there is an <asset> element, see if it has an AssetID attribute
                        {
                            //get the attribute 
                            asset = AssetIdNodeWithAttribute.Attributes["AssetId"].Value;

                            if (AssetIdNodeWithAttribute.Attributes != null)
                            {
                                var attributeTest = AssetIdNodeWithAttribute.Attributes["AssetId"];
                                if (attributeTest != null)
                                {
                                    asset = attributeTest.Value;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Item newFile = new Item
                    {
                        AssetID = asset,
                        LCID = lcid,
                        LastModifiedDate = lastModified,
                        Path = path,
                        FileName = name
                    };

                    Console.WriteLine(newFile);

                }

                //get sub-folders for the current directory
                DirectoryInfo[] dirs = directoryToScan.GetDirectories("*.*");
                foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs)
                {
                    HBscan(dir);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: when I add this in I get the error message "the best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments"

Comment: The error message is still the same with the LCID instead of the directory. I feel like there's an issue with class maybe because the threads should be working.

Comment: I changed the code again. I imported your code into a project and tested it. I got no errors.

Comment: Thank you so much! So far this seems to be working as expected :)

Comment: you are welcome. I havent run it yet so i hope it works as expected.

Comment: @user2010623 you should avoid manually managing the threads yourself. Use TPL or PLINQ or maybe a Concurrent Collection, you don't need the extra level of flexibility or the headache of fixing any bugs you create. Perhaps investigate the `async` and `await` keywords.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 4.0, you could Use TPL and use [Parallel.For/Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx) to work on multiple items at the same time fairly easy.

I just got in touch with it a few days before and it's very interesting. It gives you great performance by using multiple threads on different cores to speed up your working. Of cause this might be limited in your case due exessive IO accesses.

But it may be worth a try! (And altering your current source is fairly easy done to just check it out)

Comment: See this website for an introduction: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx

Comment: Thank you @Daniel for sharing this with us! Seems to be good to get the point and the technic behind

Comment: This is prefferable to trying to implmement the mutli threading from scratch. Don't reinvite the wheel, especially since there is nothing special about your design.

Answer (score 2):

What about something a little more like this,

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string rootDirectory = @"C:\sample";

    Directory.EnumerateDirectories(rootDirectory)
        .AsParallel()
        .ForAll(f => HBScannner.HBScan(new DirectoryInfo(f)));
}
```

After all, you only get the LCID within the loop body to write it to the console. If you want to maintian the writing to the console you could do,

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string rootDirectory = @"C:\sample";

    Console.WriteLine("Scanning through files...");

    Directory.EnumerateDirectories(rootDirectory)
        .AsParallel()
        .ForAll(f => 
            {
                var lcid = f.Split('\\').Last();
                Console.WriteLine(lcid);

                HBScannner.HBScan(new DirectoryInfo(f));
            });
}
```

---

Note that the use of `EnumerateDirectories` should be preferred over `GetDirectories` since it is lazy evaluted so your processing can start a soon as the first directory is found. You don't have to wait for all directories to be loaded into a list.

Comment: Sorry this might be a silly question, but how would I implement that within my loop of getting all the LCIDs? My FOR loop is getting all the LCIDs and I want a thread for each of these. Could I use your idea within the FOR?

Answer (score 1):

Your task could be much improved using BlockingCollection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx.

The overall structure is this: you create one thread (or do this in the main thread), that will enumerate files and add them into BlockingCollection. Simply enumerating files, should be fairly fast, and this thread should complete much faster then worker threads.

Then, you create a number of Tasks (the same number as Environment.ProcessorCount would be good). Those tasks should be like in the first sample from docs (collection.Take()). Tasks should perform a check on one individual file.

So it will result, that one thread is looking for file names and putting them in BlockingCollection, and other threads in parallel will check file contents. This way you'll have better parallelism, because if you create threads for folders, this may create uneven work distribution (you don't know have many files are in every folder, right?)